# Convergence of series of $\sin(x/n^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For the convergence of series of $\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$, is it enough to say that since, for large $n$, $$a_n:= \sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right) \approx b_n:= \frac{x}{n^2},$$ so that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{a_n}{b_n} \ \text{ exists}$, and by the limit comparison test, series $a_n$ and series $b_n$ converge or diverge together - and since series $b_n$ is a convergent $p$-series for all $x$, series an is convergent for all $x$, too?  Or am I missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: I previously asked a question about this sum [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977474/infinite-sum-of-sines-with-increasing-period). It has a nice graph of that function, along with some interesting proofs (and proves convergence, but that's not the primary focus of the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note it suffices we check this for $x\geqslant 0$. We can use that $\sin{x}n^{-2}\leqslant {x}{n^{-2}}$ and that if $x>0$ is fixed and $n>N$ large enough, $\sin({x}{n^{-2}})\geqslant 0$ (since $\sin$ is positive on $(0,\pi/2)$). Thus, by comparison, $$0\leqslant \sum_{n>N}\sin(xn^{-2})\leqslant x\sum_{n>N} n^{-2}<\infty$$

This in fact shows convergence is uniform in every compact subset of $\Bbb R$. You can also simply use $|\sin y|\leqslant |y|$ to avoid the argument that the summands are eventually positive.

Comment: Awesome, @pedrotamaroff.  Can I ask you a silly follow-up question?  Why don't we have to consider the case x<0 separately?

Comment: @LebronJames Because $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks so much, @pedrotamaroff :).

Comment: why is the uniform convergence on compact subsets, isn't it on the whole real line since $sin(x/n^2)$ is defined for all real numbers and using Weierstrass' Test?

Comment: @autodidacti You need to fix $x$ for the proof to work. Else $x/n^2$ does not go to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\lvert\sin(y)\rvert\leq \lvert y\rvert \:\:\forall\;y\in\mathbb{R}$ is enough

Answer (score 1):

It is valid for series with positive terms. However, you can use it to prove the series is `absolutely` convergent: $ \biggl\lvert\sin\biggl(\dfrac{x}{n^2}\biggr)\biggr\rvert \sim\dfrac{\lvert x\rvert}{n^2} $, hence it converges.

Comment: Ok thanks,@Bernard :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Do you know that for any $ x \in \Bbb R$, $$|\sin x| \le |x|?$$